# Add curved arrow to a NiceTabular

Tags: nicematrix

I failed to add the red curved arrows to a tabular using TikZ. I feel ashamed... :-)

I am not looking for an automated solution.

[image]

Here is the code just for the table.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 13pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{nicematrix}


\begin{document}
        \begin{NiceTabular}{r|l}
            $k$ & $u(k)$
            \\ \hline
            $0$ & $10$
            \\ \hline
            $1$ & $8,\!5    = 0,\!5 \times 10 + 3,\!5$
            \\ \hline
            $2$ & $7,\!75   = 0,\!5 \times 8,\!5 + 3,\!5$
            \\ \hline
            $3$ & $7,\!375  = 0,\!5 \times 7,\!75 + 3,\!5$
            \\ \hline
            $4$ & $7,\!1875 = 0,\!5 \times 10 + 3,\!5$
% Not good even with a straight arrow !
%           \CodeAfter
%           \begin{tikzpicture}
%               \draw[->, red] (2-2) edge (3-2);
%               \draw[->, red] (3-2) edge (4-2);
%           \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try `\CodeAfter` with Ti*k*Z commands?

Comment: I forgot to add my not working code with this. I will do it.

Comment: @SebGlav Update done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

##### Adaptations

- use `foreach` loop for automation (creating the same arrow for all lines)
- added a command `basiceval` for simple index calculation within the foreach loop
- set option `create-large-nodes` for `NiceTabular` (see [manual](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/nicematrix/nicematrix.pdf), section: "The 'medium nodes' and the 'large nodes'")
- use the `.east` of the node and `xshift` and `yshift` for fine positioning
- changed class option `13pt` to `fontsize=13pt` to solve warning

##### Note

- Instead of using `,\!` to remove the space after the comma in math mode you could also use `{,}` or as global solution `\usepackage{icomma}` (but then you have to add a space after a comma if you want it).

##### Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=13pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\usepackage{tikz}

\def\basiceval#1{\the\numexpr#1\relax}

\begin{document}
    \begin{NiceTabular}[create-large-nodes]{r|l}
        $k$ & $u(k)$
        \\ \hline
        $0$ & $10$
        \\ \hline
        $1$ & $8,\!5    = 0,\!5 \times 10 + 3,\!5$
        \\ \hline
        $2$ & $7,\!75   = 0,\!5 \times 8,\!5 + 3,\!5$
        \\ \hline
        $3$ & $7,\!375  = 0,\!5 \times 7,\!75 + 3,\!5$
        \\ \hline
        $4$ & $7,\!1875 = 0,\!5 \times 10 + 3,\!5$

        \CodeAfter
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \foreach \i in {2, ..., 5} {
                \draw[->, red] ([xshift=2mm, yshift=-.5mm] \i-2-large.east) to [bend left=50] ([xshift=2mm, yshift=.5mm] \basiceval{\i+1}-2-large.east);
            }
       \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

##### Result

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. The missing concept for me was the `create-large-nodes` feature.

Comment: Even if `create-large-nodes` is a perfect solution, you have other ways to access to the right end of your cells in `nicematrix`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

Just to leave another possibity (since the previous answer is already accepted), know that `nicematrix` creates nodes where the lines intersect in your table and at the centres of the cells, and you can access them easily:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{nicematrix}


\begin{document}
        \begin{NiceTabular}{r|l}[name=A]
            $k$ & $u(k)$
            \\ \hline
            $0$ & $10$
            \\ \hline
            $1$ & $8,\!5    = 0,\!5 \times 10 + 3,\!5$
            \\ \hline
            $2$ & $7,\!75   = 0,\!5 \times 8,\!5 + 3,\!5$
            \\ \hline
            $3$ & $7,\!375  = 0,\!5 \times 7,\!75 + 3,\!5$
            \\ \hline
            $4$ & $7,\!1875 = 0,\!5 \times 10 + 3,\!5$
            
            \CodeAfter
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \foreach \i in {1.5,2.5,...,5.5} 
                    {
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\j}{\i+1};
                    \draw[red,->] ([yshift=-2pt]\i-|3) to[out=-20,in=20,looseness=2] ([yshift=2pt]\j-|3);
                    }
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{NiceTabular}
        
\end{document}
```

This method prevents you from using `large nodes` which is a good method too, by the way.

[image: nicetabular and arrows]

Comment: Nice suggestion...

Comment: Thanks for this other option.